# Embedding a scrollable collection of plots in a widget

Tags: pyqtgraph

I am trying to write a graphical file dialog for navigating the filesystem and previewing and opening files in the format that is relevant to to my visualisation and analysis program. The idea is to provide a much more efficient way of selecting a file to analyse, than is possible with the standard file dialog. The dialog I want to create should

- show directories
- show a graphical preview of the data contained in the files which match the format of interest
- show (perhaps as a watermark) some textual identification of the file (this might be the filename, or some other information extracted from the file)
- not make the elements representing the directories and files too small when there are many of them to be shown (by leaving some of them effectively invisible beyond the limits of the widget)
- be navigable (and scrollable when there are too many to be shown at once) with keyboard and mouse
- allow selection of directories and files with keyboard and mouse

With the above information describing my broader goal, my specific question is: How can I embed a (potentially large) number of plots inside some widget, with a lower limit on the size of the component plots, and provide the possibility to scroll (using keyboard and mouse) through the whole set of plots (with the widget acting as a window through which only a subset of all the plots can be seen)?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, so could be hard to answer. Does a QListView backed by a custom model not do what you want?

Comment: @three_pineapples Thanks for the hint: it turns out that a QListView backed by a custom *delegate* does the trick, though it's not trivial. I'll post an example if and when I clean up my prototype.